# I am working with Covid-19 dataset from European CDC. I have pivoted the data frame, but it seems that the values are bing aggregated

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am working with Covid-19 dataset and have used pivot function below:

```
url = 'https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url,parse_dates=['dateRep'],index_col=['dateRep'])
data.head()

data.index.name = "date"
data = data.drop(['day', 'month', 'year','geoId','countryterritoryCode','continentExp'], axis = 1)
data = data.rename(columns={'countriesAndTerritories': 'country', 'popData2019':'population', 'continentExp' : 'continent' })

df_pivot = data.pivot(index = 'date', columns = 'country', values = 'cases').fillna(0)
df_pivot`
```

When I look at US cases on 2020-01-04 the number in pivoted data frame is "24998.0" which is incorrect (it should be 0). I will appreciate any suggestions.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`pivot` cannot aggregate, it **only** reshapes.

The issue is with `pandas` automatically parsing the index and it gets confused with months and days (so it parsed April 1st as January 4th). The simplest method is to parse the dates manually with a format after reading.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv')

df['dateRep'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateRep'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.set_index('dateRep')
```

And now we can see it will be fine:

```
df[df['countriesAndTerritories'] == 'United_States_of_America'].sort_index().plot(y='cases')
```

[image]

---

We can check to see that the parsing with your method was getting confused. Automatic parsing mixed up April 1st with January 4th.

```
df[(df.index == '2020-04-01') & df['countriesAndTerritories'].eq('United_States_of_America')].cases
#dateRep
#2020-04-01    24998     # <-- That's your number for Jan 4th.
#Name: cases, dtype: int64
```